# how to upgrade only some package and its dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm trying to emulate windows 10 arm on the jetson nano where I have installed ubuntu 18.04 arm64 edition.

```
root@ziomario-desktop:# uname -a
Linux ziomario-desktop 4.9.140 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Feb 8 00:07:34 CET 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

'cause all the dependencies that are connected to the packages that I should upgrade,qemu-kvm and qemu-system and virt-manager,I can't upgrade only these packages and their dependencies from the versions that are on 18.04 to the versions that are on the 20.04 version. I'm forced to upgrade ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04,but I can't even do that,because nvidia does not support ubuntu 20.04 for its jetpack at the moment. So,what I want to know is how I can I upgrade one some packages and its dependencies on ubuntu without to make a full upgrade. I found this :

[https://launchpad.net/~jacob/+archive/ubuntu/virtualisation?field.series_filter=focal](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejacob/+archive/ubuntu/virtualisation?field.series_filter=focal)

I have added these lines to /etc/apt/sources.list,but also the same lines but for ubuntu 18.04).

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jacob/virtualisation/ubuntu focal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jacob/virtualisation/ubuntu focal main
```

but it does not work :

```
root@ziomario-desktop:# apt install virt-manager 
Reading package list ... Done
Dependency tree generation
Read status information ... Done
Some packages cannot be installed. This can mean
that an impossible situation was requested or, if you are
using a development distribution, which some packages required
they have not yet been created or have been removed from Incoming.
The following information can help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virt-manager: It depends: gir1.2-gtksource-4 but it is not installable
E: Unable to fix problems, there are bad packages blocked.

root@ziomario-desktop: # apt install qemu
Reading package list ... Done
Dependency tree generation
Read status information ... Done
qemu is already at the latest version (1: 2.11 + dfsg-1ubuntu7.35).

root@ziomario-desktop: # apt install qemu-system
Reading package list ... Done
Dependency tree generation
Read status information ... Done
qemu-system is already at the latest version (1: 2.11 + dfsg-1ubuntu7.35).
Qemu-system has been set up for manual installation.
```

Answer (score 1):

**Don't do it.**

We *specifically* recommend against using wrong-version packages on your Ubuntu system.

We usually refer to a system with a mixture of different-release packages by unflattering names: "*horribly broken*", "*unbootable*", "*Frankensystem*", etc.

This is what apt was warning about when it said:

> This can mean that an impossible situation was requested

It's simply not a use case that releases of Ubuntu are designed for. Nor are they tested for it.

You will be completely on your own. We won't provide support for a Frankensystem beyond advice to wipe it and install a clean version of Ubuntu.

Alternately, if you know how, you can uninstall ALL the wrong-version packages from the unwisely-added source. Some folks have the patience to do this, some don't.

Consider instead asking a new question about the blockers you are encountering on 18.04.

Comment: what do u mean with "the blockers" ?

Comment: Whatever led you to abandon an all-18.04 solution.

Comment: yeah,nvidia will support ubuntu 20.04 later on this year. But I can't wait Nvidia. I want to find a solution now. can u suggest to me a tutorial where I can learn how to "uninstall ALL the wrong-version packages from the unwisely-added source" ? I need to learn the method.

Comment: Review your apt history: /var/log/apt/history.log to compile the complete list of packages that you installed. Use `apt-cache policy` on each package to determine the source.

Comment: its the time to learn a new workflow here. what u are suggesting is not enough for me to start the job. I need a detailed tutorial to learn.

Comment: what I don't understand is how to find all the dependencies. I've already gave a look using my own method and I found that almost the whole system is involved.

Comment: That why the first recommendation in the answer is wipe-and-reinstall. For many folks, it's much faster.

Comment: but I can't do that.